# What preposition is better: "Christmas celebrations at (in) the International Space Station"?

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

I was browsing [a set of photos](http://gordonua.com/photo/events/Rozhdestvo-na-MKS-Fotoreportazh-112630.html) from the ISS, with the crew celebrating Christmas, and decided to post a link on my Facebook page.

Which preposition is it better to use in this caption to the picture:

> Christmas celebrations **at** (**in**) the International Space Station?

Or maybe it's **on** the ISS?

[image]

(from Gordonua.com)

Comment: I prefer _on_ to _in_ or _at_. Of the three, _at_ would be my last choice.

Comment: I also prefer *on*, because it's what we usually use for a large vessel like a ship or a space station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest "aboard", or "on", or "in", in that order, as being most fitting. With "at", it's clear what you mean, but it's not the most correct choice.